# Kill thread manually in cachedThreadPool Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I know that when I use the `cachedThreadPool`, threads are automatically killed if they idle more than 60 seconds. But how can I kill such threads in the `cachedThreadPool`manually?

**EDIT to explain my intial problem**:

My problem is this:

I have a program and the user can start several processes. And all these processes should be executed in parallel. So far so good, but sometimes certain incoming processes should be processed sequentially. And this case occurs exactly when two processes have the same attribute (the same path).

So I wanted to create a cachedThreadPool and a new thread should always be created if there is not a thread running at the same time which has the same path as the new incoming process. (unfortunately I have no idea how to do this or what methods are available)

Now comes my thought. I always wanted to give the newly created thread of cachedThreadPool a worker, which has a queue (initially this queue contains the passed process which should be processed). Then as soon as this process has been processed, the thread should wait 60 seconds. If no other process in its queue is submitted within these 60 seconds, then you can kill it, otherwise it should always process the queue. But by always checking if there are new processes in the queue, the thread does not go into idle state and is not killed automatically. So I thought I could kill it manually.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: You can't really kill threads in Java properly in any way, much less inside a `CachedThreadPool`, so why do you think you need to do this? If 60 seconds is too much for you, it can be made shorter.

Comment: Further, the point of a thread pool is that it manages threads for you. If you want to manually kill threads there, you are defeating the purpose of a thread pool. Therefore you should rethink your approach there in general.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer, I get ur point. Then I really have to rethink my apporach.

Comment: You also need to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't ask how to do something (which might a completely wrong approach like here), explain your problem instead, so a solution can be proposed.

Comment: I edited the question, to understand my initial problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. With this additional information we can lift the confusion. 
As others pointed out in the comments, the point of a ThreadPool is that it will manage how threads are created for you. As a programmer, you only need to submit the tasks you want to be done to the thread pool and it will handle the rest, spawning or terminating threads depending on how much work is thrown into the common queue of the Thread Pool. 
What your problem is, is that you want to prevent some tasks that access the same resource to run concurrently. There are solutions for that !

Comment: There are multiple ways you could do it. The most simple solution is probably using synchronized blocks on your "Attribute" or a common object instance that represents this common attribute. HOWEVER it can be a problem if your individual tasks take the resource for a long time and if there are many tasks that want to access the same resource. In those cases, many threads could end up waiting for the first thread to finish the task while tasks that use a different resource and could be run are kept waiting.
The ManagedBlocker mechanism of the ForkJoinPool can be used if you are in such a case.